# Typescript doesn't raise error when index types doesn't match

Tags: typescript, typechecking

Why typescript doesn't raise error or warning in this code?
In map["xx"] index type is `string` but in map signature it's `number`.
should I set any config in tsconfig?

> let map: { [index: number]: string } = { };
>
> map["xx"] = "2000";

Comment: Javascript object indicies can *only* be strings or Symbols, everything else gets cast to string. So your type doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Strange that the compiler doesn't complain about *that* though.

Answer (score 2):

If you did not enable `strict: true` or `noImplicitAny: true` in `tsconfig.json`, it is an expected behaviour as the index in bracket notation is treated as `any`.

You can read this issue for details:

https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7660

Here is the playground you can see the result before/after enable `noImplicitAny`:

1. [Without `noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noImplicitAny=false&target=99&jsx=0#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDgLggbwgbQMYHsAmIkB2ArlAEYgBOAukgM5gUCWBA5hAL4QC8KHA3AChYcNAEYADFW4QARBPEy+EIfDQyAHuplSeMgEzjDigdgK0soAHTAsLABTCAlAIFA), no error
2. [With `noImplicitAny`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=99&jsx=0#code/DYUwLgBAtghgDgLggbwgbQMYHsAmIkB2ArlAEYgBOAukgM5gUCWBA5hAL4QC8KHA3AChYcNAEYADFW4QARBPEy+EIfDQyAHuplSeMgEzjDigQKA), will prompt error on `map["xx"]`

---

**P.S.**
You can either use `noImplicitAny: true` or `strict: true` where `strict` mode includes `noImplicitAny` and 6 more checking implicitly. More details can be found in the [typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#strict).

---

Although strict mode is not enabled by default due to migration and legacy problem, it is recommended by Typescript team to enable `strict: true` in [their playground comment](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=4&pln=4&pc=48#code/PTAEE0FMGcBpQO6VAawHYHsHwC4AtkATSAMwEMBXAGx2lBIwCdQAVATwAdIBlAY0YCWHHAHI6tXhjQkBAc1CEMAWABQIUJhyg8ZAG7JoOQby04KjNJEKgpAOlAAJLJH2N4ZLS8iM2oXjrReZCRVdV4yNFB8ZBxIMgBbUEZISXj4yDRCcR0tCmhvcR9QeLlGDxisMkYs0LAdXQE0eUNjLXiMYlAMsgAjKitQRqiCAWZJaTloW1Va0AAxJmHkDioyNllGDApM7WdXeCQ-CO0yDg4BKl980wIFUkoaaFmcDFAegyMBE3sWW5W1jZbHYIC5UUBkKjQV4oSCQDhRMq8FA2EhLWapc79ZgkVayOgIPBfPAnfR%20AKyAYkTaJaKgf7rTbbQhiWbEcjUWjgnbxMgwpaJaA6Mp9ZBDWkAVQASgAZaYqWbgLZHSLJMjWdrJcE9LY3ZBS6V0RqzSAADwSK0gAC5BVVev0ALTmSEzNRgADqUmIzAJHiWGkgCDu7Me4OSAH4XcReKtNeNDAiKJAAJJoFjcS1vDAYfoRADcqijMeQcdMjETKYAUunM9m4mh8ypC1Vi1J4%2000GRJBmImwG6oS0GHjgAMIYeKY7wAeWEAlboAAvKAAN6qUAaDBJ8dUL4CHAAQTQbAzRkTsFXoBaXxwADlqFRhwQkdBj2Xk6nuGeVGvLyY5tsTLOqacDAL6nueP44AACpsXCMDgbApruAgQgIABeHiAaBkCft%20nwmAAQo0hDDhCVB7mclxYTh66bisO44L8AjPgm2HnpgtHbrwu6SpAZgWMxJ6sfKX7glQCBrNA3B4TgVHnqRWDimgqr%20HakCjsQGbkJCQlrvJCCKXkVjSr0kCQppEL5J%2056KAgaD9PoVBJrEZQ4Jh9AWTp64AKIlDgDimbBzFaZZbEYNKAg9OZ2nUZgUmtAA4hk3hfA%20KQoEFHkxRgBn5IQ0oYOEZnudFoU5VYkG2ukzkZSVwlrjAACyHTUG%20zkYBwskiRwyT5Iw%20ijmghheWgFDxDVIUick7T9WO6RoLQUUTd%20KBCOFPSpUii1Cee-hpRWAmvpWH5yVQVBYPtWFHVZImmrBAhzTgEIACIpEwHhMONnmQL5L2SC5TANbxaoeGQW3XWuj2MBSMnFFInYYLYqxNBQZAUlM8FcNA-BCDgth8IIwgsFU0O2F53AAEwAAwAIwAOzUQAVtAJoZu28OIxEsgo2jtgYzA2PCLY%200mj5u62NeUhCQAvrmQA).

> Yes, we know, the defaults for TypeScript's tsconfig do
> not have strict turned on. However, at every chance we
> can the team recommends that users try migrate towards
> having strict mode enabled in their configs.